# Creating a multiple column unique index that is NOT filtered

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

If I have a definition like this:

```
...  
[Required]public string Name {get; set;}  
public Guid? DeletionMarker {get;set;}  
...
```

And I create a unique index like this:

```
...  
....HasIndex(r => new { r.Name, r.DeletionMarker }).IsUnique();  
...
```

I obtain this code in the migration:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "whatever",
                table: "whatever",
                columns: new[] { "Name", "DeletionMarker" },
                unique: true,
                filter: "[DeletionMarker] IS NOT NULL");
```

But in my case I would like to NOT have the filter applied (I don't want the same Name inserted twice, when DeletionMarker is NULL in both rows, of course).
I know that I can go in and change the generated migration by hand, but I would like to have a 'cleaner' way, if possible...
(I'm using SQL Server, just to give context)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out: I can guarantee that I made every possible google search, and that question never came out! :-(

Answer (score 1):

Just to help who falls here:
I didn't know, and I just found out, that I can use this further call to 'shape' the index, so that it becomes (in my case and needs):

```
...  
....HasIndex(r => new { r.Name, r.DeletionMarker }).IsUnique().HasFilter(null);  
...
```

and the filter is not generated anymore. Funny is that passing an empty string (HasFilter("")) gives an error during the generation of the migration.
So problem solved! :-)

Comment: How to consider adding a conditional filter without overriding EF Core filter?
I wanted to check another column (soft delete column) in an unique index, but don't want to erase the default filter it makes. How to do it?